# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: r, curl, connectivity

I'm having a problem when performing commands in R, and here are the details:

```
library(TwoSampleMR) 
ao <- available_outcomes() 
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Failure when receiving data from the peer 
traceback()


15: .Call(R_curl_fetch_memory, url, handle, nonblocking)
14: curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)
13: request_fetch.write_memory(req$output, req$url, handle)
12: request_fetch(req$output, req$url, handle)
11: request_perform(req, hu$handle$handle)
10: POST(endpoint$access, encode = "form", body = req_params)
9: init_oauth2.0(self$endpoint, self$app, scope = self$params$scope, 
   user_params = self$params$user_params, type = self$params$type, 
   use_oob = self$params$use_oob, use_basic_auth = self$params$use_basic_auth)
8: self$init_credentials()
7: .subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize")(...)
6: Token2.0$new(app = app, endpoint = endpoint, params = params, 
   cache_path = cache)
5: httr::oauth2.0_token(endpoint = endpoint, app = app, scope = getOption("googleAuthR.scopes.selected"), 
   cache = getOption("googleAuthR.httr_oauth_cache"))
4: googleAuthR::gar_auth()
3: get_mrbase_access_token()
2: paste0(options()$mrbaseapi, "get_studies?access_token=", access_token)
1: available_outcomes()
```

I've searched so many times on Google and no one gave the answer that can solve my problem, I'd so appreciate if anyone could help me!

Comment: The error suggests a URL isn't reachable, is it a repeatable error?  Do you have web access?  Perhaps going through a proxy?